# Image autofit in a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am new to Java and I met a little problem.
Can someone please tell me how I can set the Image of a JButton to be auto resizable/fitable/stretchable in a JButton when I resize the whole JFrame? The JButton is in a JPanel with a GridLayout.

It will be great if someone could write a brief explanation. I need this to complete a calculator I am working on.

Answer (score 2):

- Add component listener to the button.
- Resize the Image on Fly and update Image on the button.

---

```
Image img = icon.getImage();  
Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
icon.setImage(newimg);
```